# Segmentation fault in substitution ciphertext

Tags: c, cs50

I am implementing a substitution ciphertext scheme. It's an assignment
from the CS50 course.

The input are the substitution scheme and the plaintext and the
program should write back the ciphertext.

```sh
$ ./encrypt QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM HE
IT
```

I keep getting segmentation fault and I am not sure why. This is the source of my solution.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int result (string words);

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        if (strlen (argv[1]) == 26)
        {
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(argv[1]); i++)
            {
                if (((int)argv[1][i] > 64 && (int)argv[1][i] < 91) || ((int)argv[1][i] > 96 && (int)argv[1][i] < 123))
                {
                    k +=1;
                }    
            }
            
            if (k==26)
            {   
                char new_var[strlen(argv[1])];
                for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); j < n; j++)
                {
                    new_var[j] = toupper((char)argv[1][j]) ;
                }
                
                string key = new_var;
                
                printf ("%i", result(key));
                
                if (result (key) == 3)
                {
                    string word = get_string("plaintext: ") ; 
                    char mutated_word [strlen(word)]; 
                    
                    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
                    {
                        if ((int)word[i]>64 && (int)word[i]<91)
                        {
                            mutated_word[i] = key[(int)word[i] - 65]  ;
                        }
                        
                        else if ((int)word[i]>96 && (int)word[i]<123)
                        {
                            mutated_word[i] = (char) ((int)(key[(int)word[i]-97]) + 32) ;
                        }
                        
                        else 
                        {
                            mutated_word[i] = word[i] ;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", mutated_word);
                    return 0; 

                }
                
                else
                {
                    printf ("Usage: ./substitution keya\n");
                    return 1;
                } 
            }
                
            else
                {
                    printf ("Usage: ./substitution keyb\n");
                    return 1;
                } 
            
        }    
        
        else
        {
            printf ("Usage: ./substitution keyc\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
    }
    
    else
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./substitution keyd\n");
        return 1;
    }  
}

int result (string words)
{   
    int conclusion = 3;
    
    for (int j = 0; j< strlen(words) - 1 ; j++)
    {
        for(int i =j+1; i<strlen(words) - 1; j++)
        {
            if ((int)words[i] == (int)words[j])
            {
                conclusion = 4;
            }
            
        }

    }
    
    return conclusion;
    
}
```

Comment: for(int i =j+1; i<strlen(words) - 1; j++). Do you mean i++?

Comment: Irrespective of anything else, the code would be about eight times clearer and easier to type if you did `string key = argv[1]; int keylen = strlen(key);` just after the `if (argc == 2)` and used `key` instead of `argv[1]` and `keylen` instead of `strlen(argv[1])` from then on.

Comment: @RedYoel - Since they're apparently able to compile it, I assumed `string` was a typedef from one of the includes, probably `cs50.h`. (But my C is so out of date it could be one of the others and I wouldn't know. :-) )

Comment: `string` is `char *` from CS50.

Comment: You both are right, I learned something new :)

Comment: Unrelated: Use `if (argc != 2) { printf ("Usage: ./substitution keyc\n"); return 1; }` to avoid all those levels of indentation. They make your code hard to read

Comment: If I had a coin for every person who thinks Stack Overflow is a debugger, I'd not be rich but it's strange given how clearly it's mentioned that it's a Q/A website. Use a debugger, find the error point, see if you're accessing memory that's not yours and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Check your 'Result' function

In it, check your 2nd for loop...

```
int result (string words)
{   
int conclusion = 3;

for (int j = 0; j< strlen(words) - 1 ; j++)
{
    for(int i =j+1; i<strlen(words) - 1; j++)
    {
        if ((int)words[i] == (int)words[j])
        {
            conclusion = 4;
        }
        
    }

}

return conclusion;

}
```

> Don't think you have replaced 'i' with 'j'. `j++`

[No Segmentation fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLCK3.png)

> Then it will not show segmentation fault, pls check your code thoroughly always.